# How to convert from A to B with a single command in VIM

Tags: vim

I would like to get from:

```
0010|C|||N55555555|E0222222220010
```

to the following:

```
0010|C|||N55555555|E022222222|1.0
```

the last four digits represent numbers to one decimal place for example it could be:

```
0010|C|||N55514200|E0222222220300
```

which I would like the command to convert it to:

```
0010|C|||N55555555|E022222222|30.0
```

I would like a command to type that will convert a number of those strings in bulk. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: I have tried mapping the code provided kindly by Marth: map<F8> :%s#\d\{4}$#\=printf('|%.1f', str2nr(submatch(0)) / 10.0)#, After running VIM I get the following error: Error detected while processing C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Vim\_vimrc:

line   20:

E492: Not an editor command: %.1f', str2nr(submatch(0)) / 
10.0)# after testing the button in VIM I can see that the command stops at: |%.1f', str2nr(submatch(0)) / 10.0)# any ideas why?

Comment: No, I meant trying something _before_ asking here and receiving answers :-)

Comment: Im not a coder, literally clueless :(

Comment: That's not a good excuse. 1. If you're new to Vim (and its navigation and editing commands), you should spend 30 minutes on the `vimtutor` that comes with it (see `:help vimtutor` inside Vim). Then, there are several good resources, cheatsheets, and vi / Vim tutorials out there on the net. http://vimcasts.org/ has several short entertaining episodes that go beyond the basics. 2. Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll work out.

Comment: after reading :help map-bar I have found it was using the | to stop the code, I put a \ in-front of it to stop it. The mapped key works now however it just types the code in and I have to press enter, guess I will just live with that. Thank you all for your help and I appreciate your support! I will read up and follow your advice to learn the basics!

Comment: @Moneyboi: add `<CR>` at then end of the mapping to add an "enter keypress".

Comment: Thank you marth I added <ESC> and it works a charm now! Thank you all and sorry to come across so dumb! I am a newbie at the end of the day!

Comment: if you don't mind using perl you could do the following: cat numbformat.txt | perl -ne 'print if s/^(.+)(\d\d\d)(\d)$/sprintf "$1|%d.$3", $2/eg'

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `sub-replace-expression` (see `:help sub-replace-\=`):

```
:%s#\d\{4}$#\=printf('|%.1f', str2nr(submatch(0)) / 10.0)#
```

That is:

- `:%s#`: execute this substitute for every line in the file (using `#` as the delimiter here as I need to use `/` in the `\=` part)
- `\d\{4}$`: match the last four digits of the line
- `\=`: interprete the following:

  - `printf('|%.1f`: print a `|` followed by a 1-precision float (the second argument)
  - `str2nr(submatch(0))`: transform the match 4-digit group into a decimal number (removes the trailing 0 to avoid reading `0XYZ` as octal values)
  - `/ 10.0`: divide the value by 10

---

This transforms

```
0010|C|||N55555555|E0222222220010
0010|C|||N55514200|E0222222220300
0010|C|||N55514200|E0222222220301
0010|C|||N55514200|E0222222229301
```

into

```
0010|C|||N55555555|E022222222|1.0
0010|C|||N55514200|E022222222|30.0
0010|C|||N55514200|E022222222|30.1
0010|C|||N55514200|E022222222|930.1
```

Comment: Hi thats amazing! However when I map it to a button VIM starts with this error 942: Not an editors command %.1f', str2nr(submatch(0)) / 
10.0)#<ESC>

Comment: Read `:help map-bar`.

Comment: After some careful observations I have found the '|' is whats causing the problems because its used as a 'pipe character' to break codes. No idea where to go from there but I am making small progress :)